# Blogger API Call returning 401 Error Android

Tags: android, json, blogger

I am trying to retrieve a JSON list of Blogger posts inside of an Android app, but I keep getting this JSON as the result:

```
{
"error": {
"errors": [
{
 "domain": "global",
"reason": "required",
 "message": "Login Required",
 "locationType": "header",
 "location": "Authorization"
}
],
"code": 401,
"message": "Login Required"
}
}
```

Here is the format of my api call.

https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/BLOG_ID/posts?key=API_KEY

With BLOG_ID and API_KEY being placeholders for the actual values used in the code.

Here is the code for retrieving the JSON.

```
private class AsyncCaller extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(
                new BasicHttpParams());
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Constants.BLOOGER_API_REQUEST_PREFIX
                + "/blogs/" + Constants.BLOGGER_TEST_BLOGID + "/posts?key="
                + Constants.GOOGLE_API_KEY);

        Log.d("HTTPPOST", Constants.BLOOGER_API_REQUEST_PREFIX
                + "/blogs/" + Constants.BLOGGER_TEST_BLOGID + "/posts?key="
                + Constants.GOOGLE_API_KEY);

        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";
        Log.d("BEFORE TRY", "BEFORE TRY");
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Log.d("Executed HTTP POST", "EXECUTED HTTPPOST");
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            Log.d("GOT ENTITY", "GOT ENTITY");
            inputStream = entity.getContent();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;

            Log.d("INSIDE TRY", "INSIDE TRY");
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
                Log.d("IN LOOP", "IN LOOP");
            }
            result = sb.toString();

            Log.d("RESULT DONE", result.toString());


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Bad
            Log.d("BAD E", "BAD E");
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            try {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception squish) {
            }

        }

        if(result != null){

        Log.d("RESULT GOOD", result.toString());
        } else {
            Log.wtf("BAD", "NULL RESULT");

        }

        onPostExecute(result);
    return result;
}
```

As you can see, I am signing my requests with the API key, so that is not the problem.

I have gone into the blog in question's settings and set the visibility to public so I don't think the problem is no OAuth. I do not understasnd what else is needed to fulfill "Login Required" within the app, I would prefer if the user just be able to open the app and see the blog posts, without being exposed to what is going on under the hood. **And my https, api call works perfectly fine in a browser, giving me the exact list of results I  was expecting**, so the syntax of the API call does not seem to be the problem either, which leaves me at quite a loss.

Comment: Have you tried in a browser? Are you getting the desired result

Comment: @Indra It works perfectly fine in a browser.

Comment: Its Get method or post method

Comment: This is a get method call.

Comment: You have used post method in code

Comment: @Indra Oh, I see what you are saying, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use httpGet method

```
      HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/BLOG_ID/posts?key=" +paramAPIKEY);
```

Just replace postmethod  with Get

Comment: I misunderstood your previous comment, I apologize, thank you for your help.

Comment: Have a happy coding :)